# Values added inside of an object that are not parameters of the function

Tags: solidity, documentation, function

I've seen this in Solidity several times, but I can't find it in the documentation nor do I know how to describe it in a search engine. Say you have a function:

```
 function buyItem(uint256 _upc)
    public
    payable
    // Call modifier to check if upc has passed previous supply chain stage
    forSale(_upc)
    // Call modifer to check if buyer has paid enough
    paidEnough(items[_upc].productPrice)
    // Call modifer to send any excess ether back to buyer
    checkValue(_upc)
{
    // Update the appropriate fields - ownerID, distributorID, itemState
    items[_upc].ownerID = msg.sender;
    items[_upc].distributorID = msg.sender;
    items[_upc].itemState = State.Sold;

    // Transfer money to farmer
    items[_upc].distributorID.transfer(items[_upc].productPrice);
    // emit the appropriate event
    emit Sold(_upc);
}
```

When you call the function in the test, you pass it an object with a from and value property. How do I know when I need to use these properties and where is this described in the documentation?

```
// Mark an item as Sold by calling function buyItem()
    await supplyChain.buyItem(upc, {
        from: distributorID,
        value: productPrice,
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're called *payable functions* because they have the [*payable* modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/cheatsheet.html#modifiers).

In the [extra parameters](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id35) *from* is the address signing the transaction, and *value* is the amount of ethers sent to the transaction.